# How to auto check checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some checkboxes on my view in MVC 4. Now my question is, how can I auto check this one?

```
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Checkbox1) ( Test Box) <br /></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the checkbox auto selected, why not do it in your controller. That is a better approach because when you want the checkbox to be auto-checked, you are also implying that `Model.Checkbox1` should be true at that point.

```
Model.Checkbox1 = true;
```

or you can do it too in your view (although I suggest and prefer to do it in the controller)

```
@{
    Model.Checkbox1 = true;
}
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Checkbox1)
```

Comment: This is only answer that worked. Setting the property's value to true in the view, since I'm using Umbraco and not calling a controller except for on form submit (SurfaceController), then binding it in the view via the model worked. +1

Answer (score -1):

According to my understanding of your question. Try with below,

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Checkbox1, new { @checked="checked"})
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: try with    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Checkbox1,null, new { @checked="checked"})

Comment: add @checked="checked" portion of the HTML attributes

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Checkbox1, new { @checked=true})
```